# Как сделать так, чтобы юзерскрипт открывал нужный сайт и нажимал накнопку сайта?

Tags: jquery, test-automation, javascript-events

В общем хочу написать скрипт, который будет открывать сайт, нажимать на кнопку сайта, и вписывать в поле ввода строку из файла. Это не авторизация, а добавление элементов в  список

Какой язык-программирования, фреймворк или другой инстурмент лучше использовать

Comment: Открывать нужный сайт - `location.href = 'ссылка на сайт'`, нажимать кнопку на том сайте - никак.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

javascript для таких задач не подходит. Он предназначен для манипуляций в пределах своего ресурса. Любые попытки обратиться к чужому серверу будут пресечены благодаря Same Origin Policy.

Судя по контексту задачи вам нужно отправить на сайте форму (заполнить поле, нажать кнопку отправки).

Для этого подойдет, например, CURL в PHP. Там чаще всего это используется для авторизации на сайте. Вот примеры решения этой задачи:

https://xdan.ru/avtorizacija-na-sajte-pri-pomoshhi-curl-php.html

https://htmlweb.ru/php/example/curl_login.php

В вашем случае его нужно будет слегка доработать под конкретные нужды.

Comment: В общем решил сделать с помнью Python + Selenium гораздо проще

Answer (score 2):

это слишком большой вопрос для форума, тебе на фриланс

но подскажу эта задача для языка Python подходит больше.

А еще вопрос: "нажимать кнопку на своем сайте или чужом?"

Comment: на чужой сайт, я открыл сайт. С помощью питона можно нажать кнопку?

Comment: ну вообще по идеи да, я сам правда не знаю как)